# How to convert text values to Access numeric data types

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to convert text box values in my C# application to **Numeric** data format saved in an MS Access database. There seems to be a couple of ways to convert text to number. For instance, **Convert.ToInt32**, **Convert.ToInt16**, **Convert.ToInt64**. They all seem to work. I am developing the application on a 64 bit machine running Windows 8.1 and I have no idea which type of conversion I should use. How can the following snippet be updated to adapt it to different versions of Windows?

```csharp
oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@partyID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = 
        Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxWorkParty.SelectedValue.ToString());

oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@projectTypeID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = 
        Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxProjectType.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Comment: you will be fine, generally speaking, with Int32. as bsarkar said, the bitness has nothing to do with the OS but rather the type of data itself....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whether you are using the 64-bit version or the 32-bit version of the Access Database Engine:

- a `Long Integer` field in an Access database corresponds to `Int32`, and
- an `Integer` field in an Access database corresponds to `Int16`.

Comment: There is only Number in Access when designing a table. I saw no **Integer** or **Long Integer**.

Comment: @JasonStack You can choose between the [various types of Number fields](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-ca/article/Introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-30ad644f-946c-442e-8bd2-be067361987c#bm2g) (Integer, Long Integer, Single, Double, ...) using the "Field Size" property in the lower pane of Design View for the table. The default for a Number field is Long Integer.

Answer (score 2):

Bitness of your OS has nothing to do with the bitness of integer you want to store. It only depends on the accepted range of integer values of your ComboBox elements. For all practical purposes, you should be good with converting to `Int32`.